# d3.keys() syntax clarification?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi very new to learning JavaScript and d3.js

The following syntax creates a new array of the property names from each object held in an associative array called "data".

The property name for the first object in "data" is excluded.

```
d3.keys(data[0])
  .filter(function(key) { return key !== "date";}))
```

I'm not getting why the code below doesn't give me the same result?

```
d3.keys(data)
  .filter(function(key) { return key !== "date";}))
```

Why tell d3 to select the [0] index position as well as to filter on an object property name. Doesn't the d3.keys(*object*) method run through the associative array and return a new array containing the property names of each of the specified objects by definition? It makes me think you just need to filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is simple: you cannot pass an array to `d3.keys`, it has to be an object instead. The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#objects) is clear about that:

> Returns an array containing the property names of the specified **object**. (emphasis mine)

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/src/keys.js), you'll see that `d3.keys` uses a `for...in` loop:

```
export default function(map) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in map) keys.push(key);
    return keys;
};
```

This won't work with an array. Let's see:

```js
function d3keys(map) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var key in map) keys.push(key);
  return keys;
}

var myArray = [{
  x: "foo",
  y: "bar"
}, {
  x: "foobar",
  y: "barbaz"
}];

console.log(d3keys(myArray))
```

The same thing happens if you use `Object.keys()`, without D3:

```js
var myArray = [{
  x: "foo",
  y: "bar"
}, {
  x: "foobar",
  y: "barbaz"
}];

console.log(Object.keys(myArray))
```

And the explanation is that you cannot (or should not) use `for...in` with an array. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> Note: for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.

And the most important part:

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with **integer names**. (emphasis mine)

So, we have to pass an **object** instead. In this case, `myArray[0]` for instance:

```js
function d3keys(map) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var key in map) keys.push(key);
  return keys;
}

var myArray = [{
  x: "foo",
  y: "bar"
}, {
  x: "foobar",
  y: "barbaz"
}];

console.log(d3keys(myArray[0]))
```

Comment: many thinks for this! I looked at MDN and d3 source code but you nailed what I was missing -  "Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names."